# Resume Flowplayer or JWPlayer when stream disconnects

Tags: javascript, flash, jwplayer, flowplayer

I didn't find an answer to this anywhere on the web, so I hope maybe someone knows how to do it here.

Basically I am using a flash player with pseudo-streaming options (Flowplayer, or JWPlayer).  I am streaming FLV media files, all works ok until there is a **disconnect** on the user part (perhaps due to poor connectivity / Wifi).

When this happends, the player just marks the entire stream as if it was downloaded and then the movie gets stuck in the middle.

Is there anyway to program any of these players to *resume* (attempt to reconnect to the media server and request the file, perhaps with a Range: request) the stream and add the additional stream data to the existing buffer?

Comment: You might be able to use our API and onError() to be able to do this - http://www.longtailvideo.com/support/jw-player/28851/javascript-api-reference

Comment: I looked in the page you linked, but didn't find any method for reconnecting to the stream and starting it from a specific point and appending that part to the current buffer.

Comment: You would have to do onError(), then load() the stream again.